# Optimizing a MySql statement

Tags: mysql

This was an interview question and I have been upfront and said I'm not sure how to optimize the query - I work in the .Net stack and have been enjoying the Entity Framework for quite some time. So my skills in this area have suffered a little. This is also MySql.

So, it's driving me mad - trying to figure how I would optimize this statement. **Especially given no DB to play with**.

The statement looks much like this:

```
SELECT a.eid, a.cid, b.e_date
FROM table_A a
JOIN table_B b ON a.eid = b.eid
WHERE a.cid IN 
    (SELECT cid FROM table_A_trans WHERE `someDateColumn` <= '2014-06-01 00:00:00') 
AND a.eid NOT IN(123,124,200)
```

I'm thinking it's perhaps to do with the fact that a subquery is ran, which could bring back hundreds of results, only to then strip them out in the final `NOT IN()` clause.

So - how would you do this?

Comment: I'd start with an `EXPLAIN` and checking the indexes.

Comment: before being able to do that, i'd need a DB and data to run against, no? - isn't `EXPLAIN` for generating execution plans?

Comment: Frankly, "I'd start by looking at `EXPLAIN` and checking the indexes" would be a perfectly good answer in an interview IMO. Probably a better one than specific tweaks to the raw query without knowing what the bottlenecks are.

Comment: I suppose. Perhaps I've been looking at it too literally. Do you not see anything that jumps out as something that would run slow?

Comment: i would say ignore the `in` and `not in` at the moment and say hey the `mysql CBO is so spectacular` i won't turn them into joins. and have indexes on  a.eid, b.eid, a.cid, and a covered index on (table_A_trans.cid,table_A_trans.someDateColumn). tell them in your fictionally world this is a read-only table so no degradation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption on the sub-query is right. At the first glance that's where the problem is.

As it's a simple query, you can use it directly in the query.
I think this would work (not tested):

```
SELECT a.eid, a.cid, b.e_date
FROM table_A a
JOIN table_B b ON a.eid = b.eid
JOIN table_A_trans c ON a.cid = c.cid
WHERE c.someDateColumn <= '2014-06-01
AND a.eid NOT IN(123,124,200)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the sub query, You can use an index to obtain the results from the sub query, then after that the index will not be used

```
SELECT  a.eid, a.cid, b.e_date
FROM table_A a
INNER JOIN table_B b ON a.eid = b.eid
INNER JOIN table_A_trans a_trans ON a.cid = a_trans.cid
WHERE 
a_trans.someDateColumn <= '2014-06-01 00:00:00'
AND a.eid NOT IN(123,124,200)
GROUP BY a_trans.cid
```

is the non sub query version